# Symfony 4 - no such service exists for ObjectManager after composer update

Tags: symfony, object, service, composer-php

in my project symfony 4 I wanted to make a Composer update, something he did.

But since, it puts me an error on all my controllers when I use the ObjectManager in my constructors, like this :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

/**
     * Manager
     *
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $manager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
```

I've this kind of error :

> Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\OrdreMissionController":
>   argument "$manager" of method "__construct()" references interface
>   "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager" but no such service
>   exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing
>   "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" service.

It applies to all my controllers since they all have the ObjectManager, I do not understand what is happening

Comment: Inject `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface` instead of `ObjectManager`.

Comment: But on the doc, they inject ObjectManager : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html , so is it really a problem ?

Comment: Oh okay it's for the services. So, no the problem is solved for that. But it makes a new error on my repositories : ```Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\AbsenceRepository": argument "$registry" of method "__construct()" references interfac   
  e "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Doctrine\Common\Persi   
  stence\ManagerRegistry" instead.``` While it's Doctrine that puts this class by default when it creates the repositories

Comment: What version of Symfony are you updating from?  There have been some tweaks with respect to Doctrine in the more recent versions.  Your repo should be using ManagerRegistery (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository)

Comment: So I do not know what version of Symfony I was. Probably 4.3.x, that's for sure. But yes I also thought that it came from an update of Doctrine. As a result, in my project, I had to replace all ObjectManagers with EntityManagerInterface, and all RegistryInterface with ManagerRegistry. And now it looks good, but it's still annoying that it does not happen alone, because if one day my site is in production and I do a compose update and there are changes like this, then the site will be HS the time I understand that I have to use other classes

Comment: Doing a composer update in production can lead to all kinds of fun thing happening.  Something still does not add up.  The Doctrine tweaks happened several years ago.  Maybe early in the Symfony 3 lifecycle when autowire was being introduced.  Doing a composer update on an existing working 4.3 project would not cause these sorts of problems.

Comment: Yet I was good 4.3.x that I'm sure. I had done a dialup update maybe 3 weeks ago, and I noticed that in my new repositories it was the ManagerRegistry that was used, without it causing any error on my old repositories that were still using the RegistryInterface

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This seems to be due to the upgrade of doctrine-bundle => v2.0.0.

You have to change :

- Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface => Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry
- Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager => Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface

In your "App\Repository\AbsenceRepository" please update your constructor:

```
public function __construct(\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, Address::class);
}
```

Comment: full documentation here: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.0.md

Comment: use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

/**
     * Manager
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

Comment: In versions Doctrine 1.3 and higher, you should use : 
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry; has been deprecated on version 1.3.

Edit: In Symfony 4, Doctrine did not align the new Class to be a proper service, thus breaks. Use \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry until it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue to update Symfony 4.2 to 4.4,
In practice, I search/replace in all my *src/Repository/**
`Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface` -> `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` in USE
and
`RegistryInterface` -> `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` in *__construct*

if you use vim (`vi -p src/Repository/*.php`), here are:

```
:tabdo %s/Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\RegistryInterface/Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\ManagerRegistry/cg
:tabdo %s/RegistryInterface/\\Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\ManagerRegistry/cg
```

and my site works fine in 4.4.8

Answer (score 2):

Change the Namespace of ObjectManager to `Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;` instead of `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;`

Answer (score 1):

If not you can also come back to **version 1.12.2** of `doctrine-bundle`

> composer require doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.12.2